# Why does nothing happen after I run js scripts in hardhat?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

Still trying to run a javascript with Hardhat to deploy a contract.
`npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby`

It just has yet to run. It has been over twelve hours.

Could this be my computer or the testnet? I do not get an error thrown after compiling and I have not seen anything similar. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was doing same mistake while copy pasting the code, and with a second pair of eye of my peer he pointed out that I am missing out main() at the end of the script file

```
  main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```